# No module named 'odbAccess' python abaqus script

Tags: python

My question is around an error on python : ***no module Named 'odbAccess'***.

I have started with these lines :

```
import sys
import odbAccess
import numpy as np
from odbAccess import *
from abaqusConstants import *
from types import IntType
from numpy import array
```

For information, this script is running when I use the command Run script with abaqus.

Comment: so, what **is** your question?

Comment: Why did you expect that the module `odbAccess` exists?

Comment: might have to do with: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0235/

Comment: My question is of course how to correct this error.

Comment: @mkrieger1, he is using the Abaqus/python API, in which such a module does exist.